# Several issues when trying to start jack server.

Tags: 13.10, sound, jack, midi

Configured or not starting jack server always results in this crash on my machine:

```
JACK server starting in realtime mode with priority 10
ERROR: control open "/dev/audio" (No such file or directory)
ERROR: cannot register object path "/org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0": A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
ERROR: Failed to acquire device name : Audio0 error : A handler is already registered for /org/freedesktop/ReserveDevice1/Audio0
ERROR: Audio device hw:0 cannot be acquired...
ERROR: Cannot initialize driver
ERROR: JackServer::Open failed with -1
ERROR: Failed to open server
```

I have a midi keyboard connected i want to get to work.

Does anyone know what could cause this issue and how to solve it?